# Which Riemann integrable functions have all lower sums equal?

Tags: calculus, integration

From Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th edition, problem 13-11(d):

> Which (Riemann) integrable functions have the property that all lower
>   sums are equal? (Bear in mind that one such function is $f(x)=0$ for
>   all $x$ irrational, $f(x)=1/q$ for $x=p/q$ in lowest terms.) Hint: you
>   will need the notion of a dense set, introduced in problem 8-6, as well as the results of
>   problem 30.

(Problem 30 shows that an integrable function on $[a,b]$ must be continuous at infinitely many points.)

Now I believe the answer is that $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x)> \inf_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)\}$ is of measure zero (if you want a proof, I provide it below the divider). First, is this the most concise way to state the condition? I don't believe Spivak has introduced sets of measure zero yet, so I am curious as to how he expects the reader to do this one. And why does he allude to dense sets? Surely $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x) = \inf_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)\}$ being dense is not a sufficient condition, as the function $\chi_{[a,b] \setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ shows (not Riemann integrable).

What is he thinking of here? I hope to learn something from the method he intended.

Someone asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82844/which-integrable-functions-have-the-property-that-all-lower-sums-are-equal), but I believe the answer posted is wrong.

---

Proof for "$\{x\in [a,b] : f(x)> \inf_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)\}$ is of measure zero": The lower sum of $f$ is the same for all partitions, including the partition consisting of a single interval. This implies that for any $[\alpha,\beta] \subseteq [a,b]$, $\inf_{x\in [\alpha, \beta]}f(x) = \inf_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)$. Call this number $\gamma$. Any point $x$ where $f(x) > \gamma$ must be a point of discontinuity; otherwise, there is an interval on which $f>\gamma$, a contradiction. Now it is well-known that a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded, and continuous on a conull set (see e.g. Stein's *Fourier Analysis*, appendix on integration, for a proof). Therefore, it is necessary that $\{x: f(x) > \gamma\}$ be a set of measure zero. I claim this is also sufficient.

Comment: I think Spivak wants you to assume $f$ is Riemann integrable and then find a necessary and sufficient condition. In this case we have that if $f$ attains its minimum on a dense set then the lower sums will be equal. If the lower sums are all equal then comparing to the trivial partition we have that the $\sum_{i}\inf_{x\in [t_{i-1},t_{i}]}(f)vol([t_{i-1},t_{i}])=\inf_{x\in [a,b]}(f)vol([a,b])$. This shows that the infimum on each subinterval of the partition must be the same as the infimum over the whole interval. By repeating this over all partitions we may conclude density.

Comment: @user71352 How do we move from saying that $\inf_{x\in [t_{i-1}, t_i]}f(x)$ is the same on any subinterval, to saying that $f$ *achieves* the infimum ever (or a fortiori on a dense set)?

Comment: In my head I have divided both sides by $vol([a,b])$ and view the left side as an averaging condition on the infimums. Equality says that averaging the infimums over intervals of the partition is the same as the infimum of $f$. This can only happen if they are all equal.

Comment: @user71352 I agree the infima are all equal, but what I wonder is how we may reason from there to saying that $f$ *achieves* the infimum on a dense subset (or for that matter, at all).

Comment: Take a point $x\in[a,b]$ and a relatively open neighbourhood of this point. Choose a partition of $[a,b]$ so that a subinterval, $[c,d]$, fits into this neighbourhood. By the previous  we know that the infimum of $f$ over any closed interval is the same as the infimum of $f$ over $[a,b]$. I think there is an exercise which says that if $f$ is Riemann integrable then $f$ is continuous on a dense set. We may find a point of continuity of $f$ in $[c,d]$ and then take a nested sequence of intervals within $[c,d]$ such that there intersection is the point of continuity.

Comment: Then take an appropriate sequence that travels down the nested intervals to conclude that $f$ attains the infimum. The neighbourhood was arbitrary so we may conclude density.

Comment: Another way to get that $f$ attains the infimum on a dense set is to notice that since $f$ is integrable and since the lower sums are always the same as the trivial partition then $\int_{a}^{b}f=\inf_{x\in[a,b]}(f)vol([a,b])$. We conclude that $f$ attains the infimum somewhere by the previous equality. Notice that $f$ being integrable on $[a,b]$ means its integrable on subintervals, $[c,d]$. Since the infimum on all closed subintervals of $[a,b]$ is the same as the overall infimum then lower sums of $f$ on $[c,d]$ will all be equal and hence $\int_{c}^{d}f=\inf_{x\in[a,b]}(f)vol([c,d])$.

Comment: Repeating the previous on smaller and smaller intervals allows you to conclude density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that $f$ must take on the value $\inf\{f(x)\colon a \leq x \leq b\}$ at a dense set of points in $[a,b]$.

The difference being we already know that the function is integrable so your counter example does not apply.

If you are wondering I have verified this with the answer given in the answer book. He states that the answer rests of the fact that the function is integrable.

Comment: I think that condition is clearly sufficient, given integrability. To show necessity: we have that $f$ has the same infimum on any closed interval. Also we know that $f$ is continuous at infinitely many points (so $f$ achieves the infimum at those points, since every $x$ where $f(x) > \inf$ is a point of discontinuity). Now how do we know that there is in fact a dense subset where $f(x) = \inf$?

Comment: You must use the fact that $f$ is continuous at a dense set of points which can be concluded from problem 30. You should be able to determine this because $f$ is integrable on every interval which means $f$ must be continuous somewhere on every interval.

Comment: @Brad I'm not certain that you must use that $f$  is continuous on a dense set to conclude that provided my second proof in the comment section is correct. In any case (+1)